# Mongo: combining AND and OR

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, database

I want to return those records which have to satisfy both an AND and OR condition. The AND condition checks if the value matches that to an external value outside the collection and then I check to see if it matches either one or both of an OR condition.

This is my query using pymongo:

```
 cursor = coll.find(
                { "$and" : [
                        {"term" : 1} == events, 
                        { "$or" : [
                                {"coordinates.type" : "Point"}, 
                                {"place.full_name" : {"$ne" : None}}
                        ]}
                    ]}, 
                           {"coordinates" : 1, "place.full_name" : 1}, 
                            tailable = True, timeout  = False )
```

I can run the OR part of the query by itself. Instead I get an error saying:

```
OperationFailure: database error: $and/$or elements must be objects
```

I'm new to Mongo and Python.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is not valid:

```
{"term" : 1} == events
```

not sure what the intention was here, but if you remove the '== events' it should be a valid query parameter

Comment: Is that why mongodb states events is not an object. How could I get compare the value of events to the value of "term"?

Comment: If i remove the '== events' then it would not be able to term value would not be able to evaluate to the events value. Which is what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: assuming 'events' is a field, and you want to find documents in which 'terms' == some_value AND 'events' == some_value you can simply run col.find({'terms': some_value, 'events': some_value}) .  If this is not the case, please explain your data structure and what you want to achieve with your query in more detail.

Comment: events is a get request from an html form and stored into a list. Term has a value for example 'Obama' and if the events value is also Obama then I'm writing out data to the web browser. But events value is stored outside the collection.

Comment: Could I add the value of events into the collection under a new key  and then compare both values for these keys to see if both are the same?

Comment: Ok if events is a list eg. ['Obama', 'Romney'] and you want to see documents where the value of term is in that list, then the query col.find({'term': '$in':events}) would return documents in which the value of term is in the events list.

Comment: I did  {"term": {"$in": events}}. It seems to be working and sending the correct data to the browser. Thanks so much for your help.